# Type errors when using Office Fabric <Link> to render React Router <NavLink>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, office-ui-fabric

I would like Office Fabric's Link component to render as React Router's NavLink.  I attempted to follow the [Office Fabric docs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Component-Usage#overriding-the-rendered-dom-element) about setting `as={NavLink}` like so:

```
        <Link
            as={NavLink}
            to={href}
            activeStyle={activeStyle}
            exact={exact}
            onClick={handleClicked}
            title={title}
            className={className}
            activeClassName={activeClassName}
        >
            {children}
        </Link>
```

However, I get the following type error:

```
Type 'typeof NavLink' is not assignable to type 'string | ComponentClass<{}, any> | StatelessComponent<{}> | undefined'.
  Type 'typeof NavLink' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Property 'to' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<NavLinkProps<any>>'.
```

My question is:  How do I resolve the type error?

Comment: can't reproduce it, please provide a minimal working example https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-rain-xmiki

Comment: That codebox doesn't seem to be typechecking.  I used the zip download feature on your sample, ran `npm i`, and opened the folder in VSCode.

This image shows the resulting error:
https://ibb.co/gVhcNdY

Running `tsc` directly also emits the type error.